# confused in association in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table that has a column of `org_import_paths_id`

That `id` has the foriegn key of another table `org_import_paths`. This table has the another column of `filename`.

I want to show the `filename` of this table from that table in ruby on rails. I want to display the 
datas to the grid. Please suggest me to do the things.

Comment: Though I tried to answer your question, I would still request you rephrase your problem with some more details, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*".. I have a **table** that has a column.. "*  Lets assume that the Model name is `FirstTable` and the table name is `first_tables`. So the `Model` will be

```
class FirstTable < AR::Base
    belongs_to :org_import_paths, :foreign_key => 'org_import_paths_id'
end
```

Now if you have a object of FirstTable like

```
ft = FirstTable.first
```

You can get the value like

```
ft.org_import_paths.filename
```

Would you please clarify the line *"I want to display the datas to the grid"*.

Comment: Wow.. its working now.. Thanks.. am very new. Now i can understand from your simple and clean explanation. Thank u very much indeed.

Comment: That line "I want to display the datas to the grid" defined as am getting data from the table and displaying in the grid to view the user. Thanks and sorry for I made my question in a non understandable way.

Comment: Its ok and good to know that my answer helped you. For any further confusion just come back again :) Good luck with rails.
Thank you too to reach me 1k :)

Comment: wow.... i am glad that you helped me. I am learning rails. but still have lot of doubts. I could not find anyone to help me or teach me.. :(

Comment: go to railscasts.com, the most well-known tutorial site.  you'll never look back